# Persisting Groovy models within Spring Security Event Listener

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm

I've added an onAuthenticationSuccessEvent to my config.groovy in order to try add a Login model to a list within the users User model. The problem i'm having, is that the event listener is a closure, and as such has no HibernateSession or access to state outside of the closure.

I know its possible to bind a HibernateSession by doing something like this:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
    Login.withTransaction{
        login = new Login()
    }
}
```

The problem is that the Login belongs to a User, and needs to have the User defined in its constructor. How do I pass the User into the closure?

I want to do something like:

```
def user = grails.admin.User.read(appCtx.springSecurityService.currentUser.id)
Login.withTransaction{ user ->
    login = new Login(user: user)
}
```

but dont know how to pass the specific user in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `Login.withTransaction{ user ->` since the parameter of the closure you pass to the `withTransaction` method takes an argument which is the `TransactionStatus` - you don't get to specify the type, just the name.

But I'm not sure why you're seeing what you're seeing with regard to closure scope. The cool thing about closures is that they *enclose* their scope, hence the name. So variables outside of the closure are always available inside the closure.

You would want the `User` to be loaded inside the `withTransaction` block though so it's in the same Hibernate session as the transaction's, otherwise the `Login` save will fail since the `User` will be disconnected. And use `load()`, not `read()` since you're just setting the foreign key in the `Login`, so `load()` works best since it just creates a proxy and doesn't hit the database, but makes the id available for the `Login` save. For the same reason you'd want to avoid using the `currentUser` method since it's just a shortcut for `User.get()`.

Having said all that, this worked for me:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   Login.withTransaction { status ->
      new Login(user: appCtx.springSecurityService.currentUser).save()
   }
}
```

but since the `e` variable is an `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` you're better off using this:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   Login.withTransaction { status ->
      def user = User.load(e.authentication.principal.id)
      new Login(user: user).save()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why Can't you do some thing like below, Just fetch the user inside the closure.

```
Login.withNewSession {
  def user = grails.admin.User.read(appCtx.springSecurityService.currentUser.id)
  login = new Login(user: user)
}
```

OR

```
Login.withTransaction{
  def user = grails.admin.User.read(appCtx.springSecurityService.currentUser.id)
  login = new Login(user: user)
}
```

Comment: I cant do that because of the same reason I cant refer to user in the closure - the closure doesn't have the scope of the rest of the event handler, and thus the appCtx object is null inside the closure too. I end up with "Cannot get property 'currentUser' on null object." So I need to either hand the closure the user or the appCtx as an attribute, but dont know how.